# Characters not displayed when viewing PDF in Gmail

Tags: pdf, gmail

I am having issues with previewing PDF in Gmail. It doesn't recognize some of the international characters that I am using (it doesn't show letters like `ą` `ć` `ś`, but it shows for example `ł`). I am encoding the pdf with `Cp1250`.

Any ideas on whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the *Standard 14 Fonts* and don't embed them into your PDF. PDF readers are required to bring along these fonts but only with a limited character set which does not include  `ą`, `ć`, or `ś` but which does include `ł` which matches your observation

> (it doesn't show letters like `ą` `ć` `ś`, but it shows for example `ł`)

For details on these fonts confer the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)

> #### 9.6.2.2 Standard Type 1 Fonts (Standard 14 Fonts)
>
> The PostScript names of 14 Type 1 fonts, known as the *standard 14 fonts*, are as follows: Times-Roman, Helvetica, Courier, Symbol, Times-Bold, Helvetica-Bold, Courier-Bold, ZapfDingbats, Times-Italic, Helvetica-Oblique, Courier-Oblique, Times-BoldItalic, Helvetica-BoldOblique, Courier-BoldOblique
>
> These fonts, or their font metrics and suitable substitution fonts, shall be available to the conforming reader.
>
> NOTE The character sets and encodings for these fonts are listed in Annex D. The font metrics files for the standard 14 fonts are available from the ASN Web site (see the Bibliography). For more information on font metrics, see Adobe Technical Note #5004, Adobe Font Metrics File Format Specification.

In Annex D you'll find `ł` but not `ą`, `ć`, or `ś`.

Comment: actually, all of my text fields are set with one style:
        <textElement>
         <font size="10" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
        </textElement>

Comment: which pretty much sums it up. do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: You have not yet explained how you create your PDFs at all. The presence of both a `textElement` and a `pdfEncoding` in your comment makes me *guess* that you are using JasperReports. In that case "Cp1250" would not be a valid value for `pdfEncoding`. And "Helvetica", being one of the standard 14 fonts, would suffer from the above mentioned restrictions.

Comment: Mkl, could you suggest which font should I use so that the characters would be displayed properly?

Comment: @uksz You can first try with the fonts installed with your OS. If it is MS Windows, the Arials variants, in particular Arial Unicode MS, seem to offer quite a selection of characters.